# php laravel and stripe auto trigger for payment in specific time

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, jobs, subscription

i am working on project ( php laravel + stripe payment ) which i need to let the user pay for product by two step :

1. the first one will be triggered by the user to pay half amount of
   product's value
2. and the second one will be paying the remaining amount at specific
   time automatically without of being triggered by user

the question is : what's the best solution to apply the second step ( paying automatically in specific time ) ? using stripe subscription or laravel cron job or there is better sollution ?

any ideas will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you don't repeat the second step, I would recommend just creating another Payment (normally using PaymentIntent) at the specific time. You can use a cron job to find previously created PaymentMethod, then create a PaymentIntent and try to confirm it immediately like [Charge the Saved Payment Method step here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#charge-saved-payment-method)

Comment: but then i will let the cron job work even if there is no subscription in certain day